# Is it right when forum formed question gets up-voted, but simple question gets downvoted?

Tags: discussion, questions

I've seen couple of forum questions and they **get upvoted**:

- they are **about problem of one person in certain code**
- **code problems,bugs** are caused by mistakes and lack of understanding of programming languages
- to answer them is **needed discussion** often provided via comments and edits
- answering them **won't help anyone else** reading this question
- **it mistakes a lot of people**, because the question title looked like thing they were looking for

I've seen couple of good simple/malformed questions and they **get downvoted**:

- users posting them are newbies at SE and don't know how to ask questions at this site
- simple question, but user is newbie in certain area and don't know how to start
- user don't know very good English to explain its problem

**Is that right??**

Comment: "good simple/malformed questions" If they're malformed, then they need to be closed until they're fixed.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not right. Most of those should be downvoted and some closed, except for users who don't know English, and their questions should be edited. Please downvote most of these questions - remember that downvotes for questions are free!

The sad reality is that it's easier to see if a question is a "getting started" question than it is to see a question is a discussion question or "debug my code" question.

For questions of these types:

> - it mistakes a lot of people, because the question title looked like thing they were looking for
> - user don't know very good English to explain its problem

If you submit an edit, and the question is worth editing (i.e. please don't turn poorly-written "how do I get started" questions into well-written "how do I get started" questions), the edits *should* get approved. I try to come through at least every other day and approve pending edits, and there's so few I imagine the other high-rep users are also.